# How do I use a specific string as my salt and configure the cost factor when hashing using bcrypt in python

Tags: python, hash, bcrypt, sha

I am new to bcrypt and Im trying to use a specific field on my database to create a has with bcrypt.

what I did so far

```
import bcrypt

# example password
password = "password123"
accountName = "james"

# converting password to array of bytes
pw_bytes = password.encode('utf-8')

# generating the salt
salt = (accountName.Upper()).encode()

# Hashing the password
pw_hash = bcrypt.hashpw(pw_bytes, salt)

print(pw_hash)
```

I get this error message

```
invalid salt
```

I also want to add the cost factor of 4 and I am not sure how to. Some help will do some good.

Comment: it's quite unwise to name variables in python `bytes` or `hash` or any other name that is a builtin to python.

Comment: Your salt must conform to the bcrypt salt specification. From a comment in the [code](https://github.com/pyca/bcrypt/blob/main/src/_bcrypt/src/lib.rs): *salt here is not just the salt bytes, but rather an encoded value containing a version number, number of rounds, and the salt. Should be [prefix, cost, hash]. This logic is copied from `bcrypt`*. See also the [wikipedia article on bcrypt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt#Description).

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk so pls how do I get this to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out in the bcrypt Wikipedia article the salt passed to `bcrypt.hashpw` needs to contain a hash algorithm identifier, cost, as well as a 22 byte salt.

If you wanted to generate your own salt it might look like:

```py
from string import printable
import secrets
import bcrypt


def gen_salt(phrase: str, rounds: int = 12, prefix: bytes = b'2a') -> bytes:
    # choose a random printable byte to use as pad character
    pad_byte = secrets.choice(printable[:62]).encode()
    padded_phrase = phrase.upper().encode().ljust(22, pad_byte)
    cost = str(rounds).encode()
    return b'$' + prefix + b'$' + cost + b'$' + padded_phrase


# example password
password = "password123"
accountName = "james"

# converting password to array of bytes
pw_bytes = password.encode('utf-8')

# generating the salt
salt = gen_salt(accountName)
print("salt:", salt)
# Hashing the password
pw_hash = bcrypt.hashpw(pw_bytes, salt)

print(pw_hash)
```

Comment: please if I want to add a cost factor of 4, where do I add it

Comment: `salt = gen_salt(accountName, rounds=4)` should be all you need